# breakpoint is not hit neither in try block nor catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

Here is my code snappt. I find that there should be one excpetion thrown at line 61, because in `PublicConfig.SSO_SIGNATURE_FORMAT`, it has some problem reading one file which is not exist.

[image]

My assumption is when code runs at line 61, if it is OK with no excption, breakpoint at line 64 will be hit. If something happens at line 61, then breakpoint at line 74 will be hit. However, neither of them is hit. An expetion is thrown directly to JVM level. And I only get below output in console.

> Start to invoke 
>   
> This is in finally block

How does this happen? Line 64 and Line 74, I think one of them should be hit. But no. Could someone experience similar issue? Or I miss something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are catching `Exception`; but the actual superclass for all exceptions in java is `java.lang.Throwable`. Try catching `Throwable` instead.

Comment: @Mankarse, thanks! That explains why! I need to dig into the difference between the two.